# Error : input string was not incorrect format (I want to show other column on label from DB when click choose on dropdownlist)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

How to fix this issue?

I have view is `vw_Alldata` contains columns in use.

```
Dev_ID,Per_ID,FullName,Project_ID,Project_Name,Date_Start...etc.
```

From other relation table 
Then I  `SELECT * FROM vw_Alldata` to bind data on dropdownlist. and set

DataValueField = "Project_ID" and  DataTextField = "Project_Name"

I need to show other column from database when I click choose anything on dropdownlist such as

[sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixi82.jpg)

i use `SelectedIndexChanged` event with `AutoPostBack = true` for this code.

```
Protected Sub ddlProject_Entrance_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlProject_Entrance.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim conString As String = "Data Source=BAS-PC\BAS;Initial Catalog=PDRSdb;User ID=sa;Password=xxxx"
        If ddlProject_Entrance.SelectedIndex <> "0" Then
            Using con = New SqlConnection(conString)
                Using cmd = con.CreateCommand()
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Date_Start FROM vw_AllData WHERE Project_ID = @Project_ID"
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Project_ID", SqlDbType.int).Value = Integer.Parse(ddlProject_Entrance.SelectedValue)

                    lblDate.Text = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), String)
                End Using
            End Using
        Else
            lblDate.Text = String.Empty
        End If

    End Sub
```

When i choose any project from `dropdownlist` i get Error : input string was not incorrect format.

**Line code Error**

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Project_ID", SqlDbType.int).Value = Integer.Parse(ddlProject_Entrance.SelectedValue)
```

How should i do. Thank suggest

Picture Error
[Picture Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bucal.jpg)

Comment: Problem is here `SqlDbType.Date).Value = Integer.Parse` assigning an integer to date time

Comment: @bogey020 Try `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_ID", Val(dlProject_Entrance.SelectedValue))`

Comment: @un-lucky (Date_start data type is `Date`) i try change from 
 `SqlDbType.Date).Value = Integer.Parse` to `SqlDbType.Date).Value = date.Parse`  i get this error
**The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.**

Comment: @wingedpanther when change old code to your code.
i get this error
**Error converting data type nvarchar to float.**
`lblDate.Text = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), String)`

Comment: So the datatype for the field is `nvarchar` then why are you converting it to `Date`? or `Integer`? you can simply use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_ID",dlProject_Entrance.SelectedValue`)

Comment: @un-lucky  i try use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_ID",dlProject_Entrance.SelectedValue)` instead old code  then Get this Error:
**Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'.**
**note : Project_ID Datatype `Nvarchar`  Date_Start Datatype `Date`

Comment: @bogey020: Share what value `ddlProject_Entrance.SelectedValue` have when `SelectedIndexChanged` gets executed.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal  How to do with my code?

Comment: @bogey020: Create a breakpoint and make use of **QuickWatch** while debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying  `SqlDbType.Date` for an integer value. Change it to correct type `SqlDbType.Int`.

Comment: before i use `SqlDbType.Int` and get error too.  i try change to date

Comment: @bogey020 Show us the error you got when you used `SqlDbType.Int`

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal   I think the same error. how to attach picture in comment?

Comment: @bogey020 Attach in your post what happened when you tried  `SqlDbType.Int `

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal Ok. now I attached a picture (Picture Error)

Answer (score 0):

i can fix this issue. use this code

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_ID", ddlProject_Entrance.SelectedValue)
lblDate.Text = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Date)
```